# Iterating through Collection of Slicer Filters VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have found a solution to this, but I am curious about the behaviour of the slicer filter in this instance. I have multiple slicers and need to iterate through each slicer, then set the same value on each slicer which I do by iterating through the SlicerItems until a match is found. Here is the original (not working code):

```
Dim filter As New Collection
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim tags As Variant
Dim slcName As String

If ActiveSheet.Name = "3.CABLES_max_$AVE" Then
    tags = Array(1, 2, 3)
Else
    tags = Array(6, 7, 8)
End If
    
For i = 0 To UBound(tags)
    slcName = "Slicer_Hub_Height__m" & tags(i)
    filter.Add ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(slcName)
Next i

For i = 1 To filter.count
    For j = 1 To filter(i).SlicerItems.count
        filter(i).SlicerItems(j).Selected = False
        If filter(i).SlicerItems(j).Name = box.ControlFormat.List(box.ControlFormat.ListIndex) Then
            filter(i).SlicerItems(j).Selected = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

This code would yield an error for Invalid procedure call or argument.

To fix it, I stored the SlicerCache & SlicerItems objects in intermediate variables when pulling them out:

```
Dim slcCache As SlicerCache
Dim slcItem As SlicerItem

For i = 1 To filter.count
    For j = 1 To filter(i).SlicerItems.count
        Set slcCache = filter(i)
        Set slcItem = slcCache.SlicerItems(j)

        slcItem.Selected = False
        If slcItem.Name = box.ControlFormat.List(box.ControlFormat.ListIndex) Then
            slcItem.Selected = True
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Is this typical behaviour for collections that I'm not aware of?

Edit: Added how original code wasn't working

Comment: Might help to expand a little on how your original code was "not working"